# assigning a string to an object without double quotes

Tags: r

I have a string that is built programmatically

```
 tot=~item1+item2+item3+item4+item5+item6+item7+item8+item9+item10
```

that I need to wrap in two single quotes (without the double quotes on the string) and assign to an object `mod`:

```
# this is what I want
mod <- '
    tot=~item1+item2+item3+item4+item5+item6+item7+item8+item9+item10
'
```

I've tried:

```
string <- "tot=~item1+item2+item3+item4+item5+item6+item7+item8+item9+item10"
mod <- as.symbol(paste("'", string, "'", sep=" ")) # to try and remove the double quotes
```

but `mod` gets wrapped in backtics

```
mod
`' tot=~item1+item2+item3+item4+item5+item6+item7+item8+item9+item10 '`
```

If more background would be helpful, please see a more detailed question I posted to the [help group of the package I am using](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lavaan/X1MowpkQhwU). I am posting a more specific question on SO because I've narrowed the problem to how the `mod` object is defined.

It does work if I use `cat()` and `readLines()`:

```
string <- paste("'", "tot=~item1+item2+item3+item4+item5+item6+item7+item8+item9+item10", "'", sep=" ")
cat(string, file=paste0(string, ".lav"))
mod <- readLines(paste0(string, ".lav"))
```

but I don't think this should be necessary.

Comment: I’m sorry – it’s unclear what you want to accomplish. Your last code is the same as saying `mod <- string`, just very convoluted and error-prone.

Comment: I want what is shown in the code block with the comment "# this is what I want". The string between the two single quotes is built in a few steps not shown. I want to take that string, wrap it in single quotes, and assign it to an object called `mod`. the code block with the "this is what I want" comment is showing lavaan syntax: http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/syntax1.html

Comment: Like I said – that’s unclear. What you’ve shown is – once again, what you get when you say `mod <- string` (except that it has additional line breaks inside the string). There’s no difference between a single- and double-quoted string: `"foo" == 'foo'`. I don’t know why the lavaan documentation keeps insisting on single quotes. They’re wrong, it doesn’t matter.

Comment: `lavaan` does in fact want strings. I think @EricGreen may be confused by this line in the `lavaan` documentation: `A complete lavaan model syntax is simply a combination of these formula types, enclosed between single quotes.`  Eric, I think Konrad is right and that you shouldn't actually need single quotes (it would only matter if you were trying to create a string with embedded double quotes).

Comment: @BenBolker, you're right. i was working hard to get single quotes as instructed, but it seems double quotes are ok.

Comment: It might be worth sending the `lavaan` maintainers an e-mail letting them know that this issue can be confusing ...

Comment: In R paired single quotes and paired double quote produce the same internal values. Furthermore there are neither double, not single quotes in the resulting value, so the idea of replacing double quotes with single quotes at the ends of character values is really a fantastical notion (fostered by the screen representations of the values but having no "reality").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding R string syntax. The string you described is:

```
# this is what I want
mod <- '
    tot=~item1+item2+item3+item4+item5+item6+item7+item8+item9+item10
'
```

That is exactly the same as writing:

```
mod <- '\ntot=~item1+item2+item3+item4+item5+item6+item7+item8+item9+item10\n'
```

or

```
mod <- "\ntot=~item1+item2+item3+item4+item5+item6+item7+item8+item9+item10\n"
```

Therefore, for your problem I think it would be sufficient to run:

```
string <- "tot=~item1+item2+item3+item4+item5+item6+item7+item8+item9+item10"
mod <- paste0("\n", string, "\n")
```

If you want to output your final model without the enclosing quotes, you can do:

```
cat(mod)
# 
# tot=~item1+item2+item3+item4+item5+item6+item7+item8+item9+item10
```

Comment: Actually, according to [a discussion in their mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/lavaan/33ivgpMFkBs/SaJOj00ydCQJ), “the '\n' characters are not needed in the model syntax”

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat No, he’s not.

Comment: But `string` (with backticks) is not the same as 'string'.

Comment: thanks, @josilber. i will accept this answer because it addresses my original question and has some nice tips. but just in case folks get to this page trying to search for a lavaan solution, know that @BenBolker's comment is right. you do not need single quotes. you can assign `string` to `mod` without any modification.

Answer (score 2):

Generate data:

```
set.seed(101)
dat.test <- do.call(data.frame,replicate(6,sample(1:10, 50, replace=TRUE),
                                    simplify=FALSE))
names(dat.test) <- paste0("s1.item",1:6)

myList1 <- list(scale1.tot=paste0("s1.item",1:6),
                scale1.sub1=paste0("s1.item",1:3),
                scale1.sub2=paste0("s1.item",4:6))
```

I only made one item here, but you could apply across a set of these too, with another `*apply` call or a `for` loop ...

This works (although it gives warnings because the data are trivial)

```
fitList <- mapply(function(lhs,rhs) {
           mod <- paste(lhs,"=~",paste(rhs,collapse="+"))
           cfa(mod,data=dat.test)
       },
       names(myList),myList)
```